# Where do we mention the definition of specific terms in IEEE style manuscript?

Tags: ieee

Should we give a superscript number to the term and mention the definition in the footer with that specific number?

Comment: Provide an example.  Your question is not clear.   All definitions are specified after or before a term, E.g., let X be a set.   The n-th item in set X corresponds to BLAH.

Answer (score 0):

Editors frown upon footnotes because they cause layout problems. If you feel like writing a footnote, you should probably check whether a parenthetical remark or embedding the body of the footnote into the text would not work better. However, the IEEE guidelines tell you how to do footnotes, so they are **not** prohibited.

If the definition of a term is important, it is probably important enough to define the term in the text. IEEE places footnotes at the bottom of the page, which is the default for LaTeX.